# Node-config won't use variables from custom-environment-variables.json in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables, node-config

I'm using the node-config module for mongo connection strings and jwt keys.

For example:

```
if(!config.get('jwtPrivateKey')){
    throw new Error('FATAL ERROR: jwtPrivateKey is not defined');
```

My `custom-environment-variables.json` file looks like:

```
{
    "jwtPrivateKey": "video-app_jwtPrivateKey",
    "db": "video-app_db"
}
```

`default.json`

```
{
    "db": "default db",
    "jwtPrivateKey": "default key"
}
```

`production.json`

```
{
    "db": "production db",
    "jwtPrivateKey": "production key"
}
```

long story short - although the environment variables are set in heroku, node-config doesn't look at the values set in `custom-environment-variables.json`. I can alter the NODE_ENV and get the relevant json file's hardcoded values, but the environment variables are never used, which seems to contradict the docs

Comment: Does this also happen in your local environment? looks like something it rewriting the variable env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. It took removing the hyphen from the keys for heroku to read from custom-environment-variables.

So custom-environment-variables.json:

```
{
    "jwtPrivateKey": "video-app_jwtPrivateKey",
    "db": "video-app_db"
}
```

Becomes:

```
{
    "jwtPrivateKey": "videoapp_jwtPrivateKey",
    "db": "videoapp_db"
}
```

Heroku [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars):

> Config var policies
>
> - Config var keys should use only alphanumeric characters and the underscore character (_) to ensure that they are accessible from all
>     programming languages. **Config var keys should not include the hyphen
>     character.**
> - Config var data (the combination of all keys and values) cannot exceed 32kb for each app.
> - Config var keys should not begin with a double underscore (__).
> - A config var’s key should not begin with HEROKU_ unless it is set by the Heroku platform itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can config vars [on this way](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) in Heroku

Comment: I think I've created the vars correctly. Typing `heroku config:get video-app_db` returns the variable as expected. However, using node-config in my code to `config.get('db')` returns the value from default or production.json rather than the `custom-environment-variables.json` file. It seems to be a problem with node-config i guess? I'll edit my title to reflect that

Comment: If you suspect the problem is with`node-config`, you can set the environment variable yourself (without Heroku) and see if it works. I believe you'll find it does. The problem appears specific to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

So, I had the same issue: I deployed my app, set environment variables in Heroku, but nothing worked (unlike my local machine where everything was fine).
Seems like the problem was that I accidentally added all the `node_modules` folder to git. It happened because I created a `.gitignore` file after the initial commit was made (if I get it right).

What I did, that worked for me:
I removed `node_modules` from git and committed/pushed changes to Heroku:

```sh
git rm -rf node_modules
```

then commit and push.

This was the error message I got:

> Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header

I spent two days trying to figure it out.
I hope it's helpful.